# Regex C# How to get string from text from string to second quotation mark

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string as follows

```
 </td><td align="left" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;DaysGV_ctl02_DataGV_ctl02_SelectBTN&#39;).click();" style="width:20.68966%;">
```

How can I get the string, using Regex in C# from the beginning of the word onclick to the second quotation mark?
I am new to Regex.
This is my code so far. It is giving me an syntax error.

```
private string renderControl(string stringOfHTML)
    {
        Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"/bonclick.*[);"]""");
        foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(stringOfHTML))
        {

            stringOfHTML = stringOfHTML.Replace(ItemMatch.Value, "");
        }
        return stringOfHTML;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wildcard operator `.*`, which will match anything, for it:

```
\b(onclick=\".*?\")
```

The ? after the wildcard operator will make it non-greedy, and only match as far as the next quotation mark.

If you only want what's inside the quotation marks, try this:

```
\bonclick=\"(.*?)\"
```

I recommend a tool like [Regex Storm's Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) for testing expressions as you build them.

Comment: Works beautifully!